# Beamer - missing $ inserted

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm using `texmaker` on windows7 and I've got the following problem: if I insert a picture, I get the error:

```
missing $ inserted.<inserted text> $\end{frame}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
\frametitle{}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{../../../Info.komp.Präsi/me_fazies.jpeg}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Either remove the underscore from the name of the picture or use the option `[fragile]` for the frame. I also advise you to avoid umlauts in folder and file name: they can easily break.